# Email is Not Sending through FrontEnd with API while sending when checking in Thunder Client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, smtp, nodemailer

I am using Next.js 13.3.0 and made an api with Route handlers which sends email to user. So when I am testing my api in thunder client it is giving correct response and also email is sending but when i code it on front end although the response is also giving correct but the email is not sending.

MY API:

```
import connectDb from "@/dbconnection/mongoose";
import User from "@/models/User";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const fs = require("fs");

export async function POST(request) {
  await connectDb();
  try {
    const body = await request.json(); // getting the body of request

    const { email } = body; // destructuring email from request

    let user = await User.findOne({ email: email }); // finding user with email from request

    if (user) {
      // Getting ID From user
      const userId = user._id;
      try {
        // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
          host: "smtp.elasticemail.com",
          port: 587,
          // secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
          auth: {
            user: "digicorpoofficial@gmail.com", // generated ethereal user
            pass: process.env.SMTP_PASSWORD, // generated ethereal password
          },
        });

        const emailTemplate = await fs.promises
          .readFile("components/EmailTemplate.html", "utf8")
          .then((data) => {
            data = data.replace("{userID}", userId);
            return data;
          });

        // send mail with defined transport object
        const info = await transporter.sendMail({
          from: "digicorpoofficial@gmail.com", // sender address
          to: user.email, // list of receivers ( We are sending to body request user's email)
          subject: "Reset Password | PKTraders", // Subject line
          html: emailTemplate, // html body
        });

        return NextResponse.json(
          { success: true, message: "Email Sent Successfully", info },
          { status: 200 }
        );
      } catch (error) {
        return NextResponse.json(
          { success: false, message: "An Unexpected Error Occurs", error },
          { status: 400 }
        );
      }
    } else {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { success: false, message: "User Not Found" },
        { status: 404 }
      );
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return NextResponse.json(
      { success: false, error, message: "Something Went Wrong!" },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}
```

MY FRONT END CODE:

```
import React from "react";
import ForgotPassForm from "../ForgotPassForm";

const sendResetLink = async (email) => {
  "use server";
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.HOST}/api/forgotpasssendlink`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ email }),
  });
  return await res.json();
};

const ForgotPassword = async () => {
  return (
    <>
      <ForgotPassForm sendResetLink={sendResetLink} />
    </>
  );
};

export default ForgotPassword;
```

ForgotPassForm form submit Code:

```
  const handleFormSubmit = async (e) => {
    // setting loading to true to show the loading spinner until any response is fetched
    setLoading(true);

    // preventing form to reload window
    e.preventDefault();

    // runs the function we sent through props with email the user has entered

    await sendResetLink(email)
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.success == true) {
          // if res.success is true then showing success toast with pushing user to reset password
          toast.success(res.message);
          console.log(res);
          // setting emailSent state to true to show user that emai is sent
          // setemailSent(true);
        } else {
          toast.error(res.message);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        setLoading(false);
      });

    // setting loading to false to hide the loading spinner when response is fetched
    setLoading(false);
  };
```